# How do I solve $-by(x)'=y(x)\cdot \tanh(ay(x))?$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can you help me to solve the differential equation $-by'(x)=y(x)\cdot \tanh(ay(x))?$ $a$ and $b$ are constant.

I'm not sure how this will work, as I'm not able to compute the integral of $\frac{1}{y(x)\cdot \tanh(ay(x))} $ which I would need for solving the equation.

Comment: MathJax works in the title section :)

Comment: Thanks ;) corrected :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're going to be able to do anything better than, essentially, what you've already got. You can solve explicitly for $x=x(y),$ but the expression is only reduced to quadratures and not an explicit formula. That is, I think
$$x=C-b\int\frac{dy}{y\tanh(ay)}$$
is the best you can do.

Answer (score 0):

As @Adrian Keister answered, I do not think that we could go beyond
$$\int \frac{\coth (a y)}{y}\,dy=\int \frac{\coth (t)}{t}\,dt$$ May be, a solution would be a series expansion
$$\frac{\coth (t)}{t}= \frac 1{t^{2}} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^{2n} B_{2n} } {(2n)!}t^{2n-2}$$ and integrate termwise
$$\int \frac{\coth (t)}{t}\,dt=-\frac 1t+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^{2n} B_{2n} } {(2n-1)(2n)!}t^{2n-1}$$

Comment: So in the end it will just always be dealing with the integral I've found, right? But thanks for the series expansion idea.

Comment: @AdrianSchumacher. Yse, for sure !